# C# Modifying a Label from another class

Tags: c#, class, label, editing

Im a big newb in c# and Im stuck on one annoying thing. First of all this is the code ive got problem with:

```
        private void Refresher_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        LabelInf.Text = "Infected : " + Vars.infected; // Infected
        ZAmount.Text = "Zombies : " + Vars.zombies; // Zombies
        ZCost.Text = "Cost : " + Costs.ZombieCost; // Next Zombie Cost
    }
}
```

And :

```
 class Costs
{
    internal static double ZombieCost = (Math.Floor(10 * Math.Pow(1.25, Vars.zombies)));
}
```

And Finally :

```
 public static void ZombieBuy()
    {
        if (Vars.infected >= Costs.ZombieCost) {
            Vars.zombies = Vars.zombies + 1;
            Vars.infected = Vars.infected - Costs.ZombieCost;
        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Not Enough Infected To Sacrifice !","Insufficient Infected");
            return;
        }
    }
```

What I Want to do Is That when I Buy a Zombie , The New Cost Is Displayed In my Label ( ZCost ) , Everything is working but not the cost which Is really weird. The New Zombie Cost Is Calculated in the Costs Class and The ZombieBuy() Is in a Actions Class which is then triggered by a button  in my Main Form.

Comment: What isn't working?  When you step through this in a debugger, where does it differ from what you expect?

Comment: When I Run It , When I Buy a Zombie The Math Calculation is meant to make the price of the Zombie bigger by 1.25 (Second Code Snip) but it doesnt. The price remains at 10 and does not change. In The First Code Snip the code for ZCost is all good , ive checked everywhere tried everything but it the price still doesnt change after buying a zombie.

Answer (score 1):

You define a value:

```
internal static double ZombieCost = (Math.Floor(10 * Math.Pow(1.25, Vars.zombies)));
```

But where do you ever modify that value?  The expression which defines the value is evaluated *once* when the class is first statically loaded.  The expression itself isn't saved and re-evaluated again in the future.

Your options are either to modify the value each time you need it updated, or turn the static member into a static *method* which does get re-evaluated each time.  For example:

```
internal static double ZombieCost
{
    get { return (Math.Floor(10 * Math.Pow(1.25, Vars.zombies))); }
}
```

This property (which the compiler turns into a method behind the scenes) would be re-evaluated each time it's invoked, as opposed to only once the first time the program loads.

I'd recommend this approach over modifying the value going forward, since this encapsulates the logic and responsibility of calculating the value into the `Costs` object as opposed to making it the responsibility of consuming code.

Comment: My mind is all over , Where could I Re-evaluate it without making it into a method ? I cant think right now.

Comment: @user3787560: Well, if you don't make it into a method (or property), then it won't re-evaluate.  In that case you'll need to re-calculate it from consuming code any time you want it to change, which would mean copying/pasting that same math expression other places in your code.  Why not just make it a property?  This is *exactly* what properties are for.

Comment: @user3787560: "as organized as possible"?  That... doesn't make a lot of sense.  You can arrange your code however you like.  It's just as easy to put a property/method/constructor/etc. on an object as it is to put a value on an object.